# Split HTML tr elements into PHP array

Tags: php, html, arrays, html-table

I've already posted this thread but never explained it very well, so I deleted it and am rewriting it.

My php script sends a cURL request to a website which will then output a HTML table, I then will use that table which has 7 TR elements in it, each TR element will have 6 TD elements within it.

This means that the HTML table is technically already coded on the page, what I want to do is split each TR into a separate PHP array, with the TD's accessible through that key.

So for example:

> `Table
>
>   -- tr1
>
>   ----td
>
>   ----td
>
>   ----td
>
>   ----td
>
>   ----td
>
>   ----td
>
>   -- tr2
>
>   ----td
>
>   ----td
>
>   ----td
>
>   ----td
>
>   ----td
>
>   ----td`

I will then be able to do:
`echo $TRArray[1][3]`
That will then echo 'td' because that is the value of the 2nd TD element on the first TR array

I'm not sure if I am explaining this very well, but that is what I want to be able to do

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you give us one full line of the data you obtain from the website? Shouldn't it look something like <tr><td>data</td><td>data</td>......<tr>?

Comment: @TimSPQR yes, it is exactly like that. The TDs have classes, but the TRs do not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you php have php-dom enabled:

```
$export = array();
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html);
libxml_clear_errors();

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$tr_no = 0;
foreach( $xpath->evaluate('//tr') as $sel ){
    $export[$tr_no] = array();
    $td_no = 0;
    foreach( $sel->childNodes as $td ){
       if( strtolower( $td->tagName )  == 'td' ){
            $innerHTML = '';
            foreach ($td->childNodes as $child){
                $innerHTML .= $td->ownerDocument->saveHTML($child);
            }
            $export[$tr_no][$td_no] = $innerHTML;
            $td_no++;
       }
    }
    $tr_no++;
}

var_dump( $export );
```

Comment: thanks, I will give that a try when I'm on my laptop :-)

Comment: @MarkEriksson Would you please set the answer as right answer? If it works for you.